# Common Emitter amplifier is used as

Tags: amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, inverting-amplifier, common-emitter

Common Emitter Amplifier is used as
A)Current Amplifier
B)Voltage Amplifier
C)Power Amplifier
D)Frequency Modulator

The answer according to key was Voltage Amplifier but I have given Power Amplifier as the CE has moderate Ai and Av hence high Power gain....also it acts as Voltage as well as current Amplifier.....so what's the correct answer? We have to challenge the answers which we feel are wrong with proof!

Comment: You've already answered your question haven't you? If you have Ai and Av, then by definition, you have amplified power. On the other hand, one could argue that Av is generally much higher depending upon topology so that may be why the answer says a voltage amplifier. Much in electronics terminology is about relative qualities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common collector (emitter follower) is a pure current amplifier. In fact, it has a tiny loss in terms of voltage.

Common base is a pure voltage amplifier. It has a tiny loss in terms of current.

Common emitter has both voltage and current gain in most configurations, and so is best characterized as a power amplifier.

I don't know what would constitute "proof" ... it's just a matter of evaluating any given circuit for both kinds of gain.